# When ever I try to login to mongo db atlas A white blank screen shows . Just logging in nothing else

Tags: mongodb, authentication, mongodb-atlas

To do my mern project I logged in using My registered credentials , when ever i login only a blank screen is showing and just loading infinately .I even tried creating a new account . Still the problem exist

Comment: Ask your Admin to whitelist your IP. See if that works

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.